# java mail smtp connection problem

Tags: java, email, smtp, connection

i am trying the below example to send mail using ssl picked from [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0570.html) and changed with my credentials as below and get exception as shown, can you please help me to get through it

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

import java.util.Properties;


public class SimpleSSLMail {

    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
    private static final int SMTP_HOST_PORT = 25 ;//465;
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "xxx@yyy.com";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "xxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       new SimpleSSLMail().test();
    }

    public void test() throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        // props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setSubject("Testing SMTP-SSL");
        message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             new InternetAddress("myid@gmail.com"));

        transport.connect
          (SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);

        transport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:xx.xx.xx.xx, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
```

Comment: the error message is pretty straight forward , most probably a network problem . Can you verify that ?

Comment: tried telnet to smtp only  any other way to check connection, username and pwd please tell me

Comment: If you can't telnet you can easily set up a mail client to point to it using those credentials and check that way.

Comment: ok , so the host is reachable ? does you system use a proxy to connectto the host ?

Comment: @caps: i can telnet and it gets connected  amal: please tell the way to check if system uses prxy 2 connect

Comment: depends on your OS . In windows I guess I can open up the connections tab from control panel and check if there's a proxy defined . Anyway If you are using a proxy , you need to specify it in code . Use Google . You'd need something like http://zone817.blogspot.com/2010/08/reading-from-url-using-java-program_02.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of problem  occurs due to a network problem . May be you require authentication, you may have wrong username , password .

Anyways you are missing in a lot of things in your code.
**Example to obtain a proper SSL connection with gmail server**

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                           "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

***I don't see this any where in your code. Then where is the method to authenticate ?***

Just check out the following links :

[Sending E-mail Using Gmail In Java](http://suhail3.blogspot.com/2011/07/program-to-send-e-mail-using-gmail-in.html)  *Here you have a choice of using TLS or SSl*

[Java Mail API](http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/index.shtml)

[E-mailing through Java](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/javamail.html)

[keys used in java mailing system for your reference](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html)